# Any advantages of using a Power Plate for planks?

Tags: abdominals, core, planks

My gym instructor told me that doing planks with elbows on the vibrating Power Plate gives better results than a normal plank on the floor... Does anyone know if there's some truth to it or is it just bro science?
I'd appreciate it if the answers stated whether they are based on experience or literature.

Answer (score 2):

I'd give it some credit, and say that planking on a vibrating surface *will* have some extra yield, since you have to activate more core muscles to keep stability.

That said, the Power Plate is NOT worth paying for. It's a niche product, and whatever benefit it does give, can be offered by conventional equipment found in any gym.

Answer (score 0):

I briefly scanned PubMed for relevant studies and it seems that most have been done in the sick, elderly or sedentary individuals and it is used more in a rehab setting. Some studies do show an, albeit small, effect on strength so it doesn't seem like you can just discard any claims made by vibration training advocates wholesale. However, it doesn't seem to do that much so my advice would just be to do the type of training that you enjoy the most. Like the vibration plate? Go for it. Don't like it? Well, just don't.

Comment: Can you link these studies?

Answer (score -2):

My doctor recommends it for all workouts, including stretching.  He said that stretching on the plate for one minute is like stretching for 10 minutes.  The same with any workout you do.  The benefits are increased exponentially.